# How to Use Method via Reflection Java

Tags: java, android, reflection

I am trying to use reflection instead of including a jar file.  I want to do this to reduce my apk size when I am not using the jar code...but if I include the code, I must include the jar.  That being said, I am trying to grasp reflection and not doing well.

I have this code to see the methods available (and it works):

```
//initialize method params
Class[] paramInitialize = new Class[2]; 
paramInitialize[0] = Activity.class;
paramInitialize[1] = String.class;

try {
    Logger.i(DEBUG_TAG, "try statement");
    Class <?> tremorVideoCls = Class.forName("com.tremorvideo.sdk.android.videoad.TremorVideo");
    Class <?> tremorSettingsCls = Class.forName("com.tremorvideo.sdk.android.videoad.Settings");
    Object object = tremorVideoCls.newInstance();
    String apkName = this.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0).sourceDir;
    loader = new dalvik.system.PathClassLoader(apkName, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
    tremorVideoCls = loader.loadClass("com.tremorvideo.sdk.android.videoad.TremorVideo");
    Method m[] = tremorVideoCls.getMethods();
    Method declaredM[] = tremorVideoCls.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        Logger.i(DEBUG_TAG, "getMethods is " + m[i].toString());
    }
    Field []field = tremorSettingsCls.getFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
        Logger.i(DEBUG_TAG, "getFields is " + field[i].toString());
    }
    Method tremorInitialize = tremorVideoCls.getMethod("initialize", paramInitialize);
    Logger.i(DEBUG_TAG, "tremorInitialize is " + tremorInitialize.toGenericString());
//  tremorInitialize.invoke(object, this, ACCUWX.TREMOR_ADSPACE_TEST);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException x) {
 ...
```

BUT, I get a logcat error throwing an exception:

```
08-06 11:48:51.134: W/System.err(11688): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: initialize [class android.app.Activity, class java.lang.String]
```

Here is the logcat printing out that method:

```
08-06 11:48:51.118: I/Flagship/MainActivity(11688): getMethods is public static void com.tremorvideo.sdk.android.videoad.TremorVideo.initialize(android.content.Context,java.lang.String)
```

I'm not sure what do try next...any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please also post the signature of the methods you are trying to invoke?

Comment: this is from my logcat to show me the parameters public static void com.tremorvideo.sdk.android.videoad.TremorVideo.initialize(android.content.Context,java.lang.String)

Comment: Did you try replacing the first parameter with android.content.Conte‌​xt.class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method which you are trying to invoke is

```
public static void com.tremorvideo.sdk.android.videoad.TremorVideo.initialize(android.content.Conte‌​xt,java.lang.String)
```

and the error is

```
08-06 11:48:51.134: W/System.err(11688): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: initialize [class android.app.Activity, class java.lang.String]
```

It clearly indicates that the method expects `android.content.Conte‌​xt` but what you are passing `android.app.Activity`

In the call

```
tremorInitialize.invoke(object, this, ACCUWX.TREMOR_ADSPACE_TEST);
```

instead of passing `this` you should pass an instance of `android.content.Conte‌​xt`.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: But because Activity extends Context a cast (Context) this is just fair enough.

Comment: @Peter, what would be the problem then? I am not very well - versed with Android.

Comment: There is no method initialize(Activity act, String arg) in the class  com.tremorvideo.sdk.android.videoad.TremorVideo

Comment: And: You are loading the class for yourself, but retrieving the Class -object for it before. If the loading really is necessary, then your call forName should result in a ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: simply paramInitialize[0] = Context.class; and the method should be found.

Comment: putted that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not the invocation of the method but the call to retreiving the method.
Because the Class[] is initialized with Activity.class, a method with the signature
 
     void initialize(Activity activity, String string) is searched for.

This method doesn't exist. 
So it should be

```
 paramInitialize[0] = Context.class;
```

to find the method

```
initialize(Contex ctxt, String arg).
```